# Using SO, SU, SF Logos and Colour Schemes in Third Party Apps/Tools

Tags: discussion, copyright, logo, design

I am building an App to access Stackoverflow, I would very much like to use the logo and colour scheme to give users a sense on continuity.

But at the same time I don't want people to think it a SO product or endorsed by them in any way.

The app will be free (but I may ask for donations).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the footer of every page:

> site design and logo is © 2009 stackoverflow.com llc

I would email team@stackoverflow.com and ask Jeff/Joel directly.